# Form Factors confusion in Radiosity papers

Tags: radiosity

I feel a bit confused about the use of $F_{ij}$ and $F_{ji}$ in Radiosity papers. $F_{ij}$ should be the fraction of energy leaving patch $i$ that arrives at patch $j$.

If you take the original radiosity paper *("Modeling the Interaction of Light Between Diffuse Surfaces", by Goral, Torrance, Greenberg, and Battaile, at SIGGRAPH 84)*, the radiosity equation is expressed as:
$$
B_{j} = E_{j} + \rho_{j} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n B_{i} F_{ij}
$$
and they explicitly mention that all radiosities are measured in $W/m^2$ and that $F_{ij}$ is the *"form factor and represents the fraction of radiant energy leaving surface i and impinging on surface j"* (sic).

Now if you take another famous paper *("The Hemi-Cube. A Radiosity solution for complex environments", by Cohen and Greenberg, at SIGGRAPH 85)* you see that their equation 1 is:
$$
B_{i} = E_{i} + \rho_{i} \sum\limits_{j=1}^n B_{j} F_{ij}
$$
and they also explicitly say that radiosities are expressed in $W/m^2$ and that $F_{ij}$ is the *"the fraction of the energy leaving one surface which lands on another surface"* (sic).

Yes, I didn't make a mistake, both papers use $F_{ij}$ even if they switched the $i$ and $j$ indices and even if they're formulating the classical gathering radiosity (the shooting-based progressive refinement approach came later, in SIGGRAPH 88).

Moreover, to add more into the confusion, some books follow the SIGGRAPH 84 paper equation (*Foley, van Dam, Feiner, Hugues*, for example), while others use the SIGGRAPH 85 paper equation (*Sillion & Puech*, for example).

I know $F_{ij}$ and $F_{ji}$ get reversed if you express the equation in radiant energy $(W)$ instead of radiosities $(W/m^2)$ because of the reciprocity relationship $F_{ij}A_{i}=F_{ji}A_{j}$, but however, both equations above are explicitly radiosity-based, in $W/m^2$.

Is there any mistake in radiosity papers? In that case, what equation is right? Or maybe I'm missing some piece in this puzzle?